# Die rolling contest problem

Tags: probability-theory

I got this problem as part of an interview...

> Problem Statment:
>
> You have two players, Frank and Jane, that take turns
> in rolling a fair k-sided die. Whoever rolls a k first wins the game.
> The Python program should output the probability that Frank wins the
> game for k=6 thru 99. That is, the output will be an array of probabilities where index 0
> is the probability when k = 6; index 1 when k = 7; etc.

Note that it doesn't state who goes first or put any limit on the number of rolls. I asked for clarification because it sure seems to me the probability of Frank winning is always 50%, regardless of the value of k. I believe there is a slight advantage if Frank rolls first, but that's not in the problem statement. The person responded insisting that the probability of Frank winning *does* depend on k. I don't see it.

Very similar probably is covered here: [Probability of winning a game by rolling the die first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389480/probability-of-winning-a-game-by-rolling-the-die-first)
but I think that solution depends on knowing who rolls first correct?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense without specifying who goes first. We can't just assume there's a 50% probability that Frank does roll first, either. Seems like just a mistake in the problem statement. (And who's Bob? ;)

Comment: In an interview the real question might be whether you were prepared to ask for clarification.

Comment: If $k=2$ then the first person who rolls has a $2/3$ chance of winning. If $k=1$ then the person who goes first wins every time. This advantage gets less as $k$ gets larger but we should not expect it ever to completely disappear; it's just that at some point it's going to take too many decimal places to write and we just output $0.5$ instead.

Comment: The size of the advantage of rolling first depends on $k$, so if your program is expected to give $94$ different values as $k$ changes then the question presumably wants the probabilities for the player rolling first. A program that repeats `0.5` $94$ times would be rather dull.

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ denote the probability that Frank wins the game.

### If Frank rolls first

1. There is a probability of $\frac{1}{k}$ that Frank wins on the first roll.
2. Otherwise (with probability $1 - \frac{1}{k} = \frac{k-1}{k}$), Jane gets the opportunity to roll.  Given this, there is a $\frac{1}{k}$ probability that she wins on this roll.  The absolute probability that this happens is thus $\frac{k-1}{k^2}$.
3. Otherwise (with probability $\frac{k-1}{k} - \frac{k-1}{k^2} = \frac{k^2-2k+1}{k^2}$), we arrive at an equivalent of state #1, as if a new game starts, and Frank rolls first.

Thus, the probability that Frank wins the game is:

$$p = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{k^2-2k+1}{k^2}p$$

Solving for $p$ in terms of $k$ gives:

$$\boxed{p = \frac{k}{2k-1}}$$

### If Jane rolls first

Then she's in the same position as Frank in the previous scenario.  Thus, the probability that she wins the game is $\frac{k}{2k-1}$.  And the probability that Frank wins is the complement of this, $p = 1 - \frac{k}{2k-1}$, or:

$$\boxed{p = \frac{k-1}{2k-1}}$$

### In conclusion

Yes, there *is* an advantage to rolling first.

Answer (score 6):

Moderately alternative approach.

Given a $~k~$ sided die, let $~P~$ denote the probability that the first player wins, and $~Q~$ denote the probability that the second player wins.  This implies that $~P + Q = 1.$

Then you have the equation

$$P = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{k-1}{k} \,Q = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{k-1}{k} \,(1-P). \tag1 $$

The equation in (1) above is explained by saying that either the first player wins immediately, or the first player *steps into the position* of being the second player.  That is, if the first player does not win on their very first roll, the probability of their winning is now equivalent to the probability of the second player winning, at the start of the game.

Then, you have

$$P + P \,\frac{k-1}{k} = \frac{1}{k} + \frac{k-1}{k} = 1 \implies $$

$$P \times \frac{2k - 1}{k} = P \times \left[ ~\frac{k}{k} + \frac{k-1}{k} ~\right] = 1 \implies $$

$$P = \frac{k}{2k-1}.$$

Comment: The "second player takes on the first player's probabilities" seems to be common in game theory proofs, but idk its name.